Does a gray water system need a drain trap to meet code?
If I put in a gray water system and plumb my shower to an outside 250 gallon tank which I place in the ground, do I need to have a P-trap?
My intent/idea is to plumbing my master shower out to a 250 gallon IBC tote for the garden. I am wondering if code specifies whether or not you need a trap for that and this would be legal.

Many codes don't even permit greywater at all, or define it as only coming from the kitchen sink, since showers, lavatories and clothes washers are likely to have trace fecal material. I don't know about your local code. I can't see any good reason NOT to have a trap, as even without bulk feces a tank full of dirty water stagnating is likely to stink. The only way I'd see not having a trap making any sense would be if the pipe went to a filter-inlet that did not store any water (so, dumps it into the head of a reed-bed or sand filter, for instance) and even there a trap will stop drafts.
